# How to compute future's (tomorrow's) distribution given today's?

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions

Marital status can be defined as single, married, separated, or divorced.

Today's distribution is:

```
Single = 49%
Married = 25%
Separated = 15%
Divorced = 11%
```

I am supposed to find the distribution for tomorrow. I am also given a table simply entitled "Table 1":

```
             Single'    Married'    Separated'    Divorced'
Single        0.85       0.12         0.02          0.01
Married       0          0.88         0.08          0.04
Separated     0          0.13         0.45          0.42
Divorced      0          0.09         0.02          0.89
```

So how does one find "distribution of people tomorrow"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the  $4\times 4$ matrix towards the end. That is the **second** table, stripped of the header words. So it is just a $4\times 4$  square array of numbers. This matrix is called the **transition matrix**. Let us call it $M$.

Now let $v_0$ be the **row** vector consisting of the numbers in your **first** table, written as a row.

Then the row vector $v_1$ that gives the probabilities "tomorrow," or more likely next year, is given by
$$v_1=v_0M.$$
If you know about multiplying a row vector by a matrix, the rest should be easy.
But some background in Linear Algebra would be useful for full understanding. And for later work you may need information about other topics in Linear Algebra to deal effectively with transition matrices.

**Remarks:** $1.$ In much of Linear Algebra, there is a preference for column vectors. To write things in that style, let $M^T$ be the **transpose** of the matrix we get from the second table. Write the initial distribution as a *column vector* $v_0$. Then we gt $v_1=M^Tv_0$.

$2.$ To find the distribution vector $v_2$ after two time period, just multiply by $M$ (or $M^T$) again.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I am not sure I completely understand (given that English is not my primary language). Are you saying that in order to find probabilities for tomorrow, I have to multiply the transitional matrix (M) with the first column (v0)? If so, where do the numbers 49%, 25% etc come into play? For the record, I know how to multiply a matrix with a vector... But I don't understand how that solves a problem of finding percentages like in the first codeblock.

Comment: I have added **emphases** in a couple of places. The vector $v_0$ is your **first** table, precisely the numbers $0.49$, $0.25$, and so on that you are asking about.  Do the calculation, give me the answers (they can be a row  if formatting the column shape is a nuisance) and I will tell you whether you are right.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, really appreciated. I have multiplied the transition matrix with the vector from the first "table" and I got the  0.45 , 0.24 , 0.15 , 0.12 (this of course being a column). The numbers kind of look right, but what worries me is that they do not add up to 1.00...

Comment: You are right to worry, they must add up to $1$.  I made a mistake, the matrix is written backwards from the usual one. We have to write $v_0$ as a **row**, and calculate $v_0M$. Or else take the transpose $M^T$ of the matrix as written, and use M^Tv_0$.

Comment: Once again thank you - I multiplied the two matrices and have gotten accurate results that add up to 1.00!

Comment: @Deusdies: I have changed the answer, to reflect the fact that the natural matrix one gets from the table forces multiplication by $M$ on the right.